# Cannot decode POST request body in the backend: raise MultiValueDictKeyError(key)

Tags: python, django, backend

I send JSON data in the POST request body to Python backend (Django). In the backend I receive this content:

```
body_unicode = request.body.decode('utf-8')
print(body_unicode)
```

> {"holdingTime":0,"asma40":49,"asma60":18,"temperature":9,"visibility":9999,"windIntensity":1.5,"windDirection":"VRB","airportDepDelay":8,"csvData":"NUM,AIRLINE_ARR_ICAO,WAKE,SIBT,SOBT,PLANNED_TURNAROUND,DISTANCE_FROM_ORIGIN,DISTANCE_TO_TARGET\n1,AEA,H,2016-01-01
>   04:05:00,2016-01-01 14:10:00,605,9920.67,5776.89\n2,AEA,H,2016-01-01
>   04:25:00,2016-01-01 06:30:00,125.0,10060.80,483.93\n3,AVA,H,2016-01-01
>   05:05:00,2016-01-01 07:05:00,120.0,8033.86,8033.86\n4,IBE,H,2016-01-01
>   05:20:00,2016-01-01 10:40:00,320.0,6000.00,8507.73\n5,IBE,H,2016-01-01
>   05:25:00,2016-01-01 10:50:00,325.0,6698.42,6698.42\n6,IBE,H,2016-01-01
>   05:30:00,2016-01-01
>   08:10:00,160.0,10699.06,1246.30\n7,IBE,H,2016-01-01
>   05:30:00,2016-01-01 11:00:00,330.0,9081.35,8033.86\n8,IBE,H,2016-01-01
>   05:40:00,2016-01-01 11:35:00,355.0,5776.89,8749.87\n9,ANE,M,2016-01-01
>   05:50:00,2016-01-01 14:50:00,540.0,284.73,284.73\n10,ETD,H,2016-01-01
>   06:35:00,2016-01-01 08:00:00,85.0,5647.10,5647.10\n11,IBS,M,2016-01-01
>   06:50:00,2016-01-01 08:00:00,70.0,547.36,1460.92\n12,IBE,H,2016-01-01
>   06:50:00,2016-01-01
>   10:35:00,225.0,6763.16,6763.16\n13,IBE,H,2016-01-01
>   06:50:00,2016-01-01
>   10:50:00,240.0,7120.40,7120.40\n14,IBE,H,2016-01-01
>   06:50:00,2016-01-01
>   10:55:00,245.0,7010.08,6000.00\n15,QTR,H,2016-01-01
>   06:55:00,2016-01-01 08:30:00,95.0,5338.52,5338.52\n16,IBS,M,2016-01-01
>   07:00:00,2016-01-01 07:45:00,45.0,485.52,1721.09\n17,IBS,M,2016-01-01
>   07:00:00,2016-01-01 07:45:00,45.0,394.98,429.37\n18,ELY,M,2016-01-01
>   07:05:00,2016-01-01 08:30:00,85.0,3550.48,3550.48\n19,AAL,H,2016-01-01
>   07:05:00,2016-01-01
>   12:05:00,300.0,5925.61,5925.61\n20,TVF,M,2016-01-01
>   07:30:00,2016-01-01 08:10:00,40.0,1030.31,1030.31\n"}

But if I do this, I get error:

```
body_unicode = request.body.decode('utf-8')
body = json.loads(body_unicode)
print(body)
```

Error:

> Internal Server Error: /batch_predict Traceback (most recent call
>   last):   File
>   "/Users/tuter/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
>   line 34, in inner
>       response = get_response(request)   File "/Users/tuter/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py",
>   line 126, in _get_response
>       response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)   File "/Users/tuter/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py",
>   line 124, in _get_response
>       response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)   File "/Users/tuter/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py",
>   line 54, in wrapped_view
>       return view_func(*args, **kwargs)   File "/Users/tuter/Desktop/test/backend/views.py", line 192, in
>   batch_predict_endpoint
>       body = json.loads(body_unicode)   File "/Users/tuter/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/json/**init**.py", line 354, in
>   loads
>       return _default_decoder.decode(s)   File "/Users/tuter/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in
>   decode
>       obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())   File "/Users/tuter/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in
>   raw_decode
>       raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char
>   0)

**Update:**

If I do this:

```
sample_data = request.POST['csvData']

print("sample_data",sample_data)
```

then this error appears:

```
    sample_data = request.POST['csvData']
  File "/Users/tuter/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py", line 79, in __getitem__
    raise MultiValueDictKeyError(key)
```

Comment: Your code doesn't match your exception and the exception does't match the data. You have `json.loads(io.StringIO(body_unicode))` in your code which will fail because `loads()` is expecting a string. But your exception shows you're actually using it the correct way with `json.loads(body_unicode)`. As for the data, it's complaining about the first character which is OK in data. It also works fine if I just run this locally.

Comment: Why did you pass it onto StringIo? Why not directly to json.loads?

Comment: @DanielRoseman: I removed StringIO and the issue is the same. In fact I added StringIO because I was experimenting.

Comment: @kichik: That's the case that it runs locally outside of React.js and Django, just inside Python compler. I removed StringIO and the issue is the same. I suspect that React.js corrupts the data in some way.

Answer (score 0):

In django you do not need to load your request body with json package you can get your data from request by a json key:

```
def my_view(request):
   sample_data = request.POST['sample_key']
   # statements
```

Comment: If I do so, I get the error `raise MultiValueDictKeyError(key) django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'csvData'`. The data that arrives to Django is shown in my post. I am absolutely lost and do not understand what is happening. I appreciate so much if you could help. Thanks!